# htaccess redirect from subdomain to ip

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ip

I have an alias like ***.domain.com** to **domain.com**.

So, I need to do a redirect from **a.domain.com** to a specific **IP** and on the other sub domain like **b.domain.com** or **z.domain.com** send error 404.

I understand that it is necessary to dig into **.htaccess** but can not find the right solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the solution.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a.domain\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule (.*) http://111.111.111.111/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/404/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That was a good solution but how about vhosts ? should we add that using proxypass ?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would fix the name server to point a.domain.com to the proper server. If not, you should use virtual hosting and then use a redirect (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) to get you the right address.

Comment: Ok, I see. Yes, we use virtual hosting but our admin make exactly *.domain.com, with asterisk and all. No another fird level domain.

So now all third level domain show content from domain.com.